# Verify over 200 List elements on a page in Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some 200 elements who's mark-up is as follows:

```
<span id="1356329740258" class="pagename">Sport & leisure</span>
<span id="1356329740259" class="pagename">Food & drink</span>
<span id="1356329740260" class="pagename">Household</span>
<span id="1356329740261" class="pagename">Gardening</span>
```

I can access them with Webdriver in a fairly ugly manner:

```
List<WebElement> elements;
elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath( ".//*[starts-with(@id, '135')]"));
```

...Because each starts with a '135'.
   But `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pagename");` 
...does not work, perhaps something to do with the '' tags

What I now need to do, is do a .getText() for each element in the list and verify it against the expected, corresponding array value. I'm starting off thinking of this method:

```
String[] expected = {"Sport & leisure", "Food & drink", "Household", "Gardening"};
List<WebElement> elements = select.find.Elements(By.xpath( ".//*[starts-with(@id,'135')]"));

// compare #array items with #found elements in List 
    if (expected.length != elements.size()) {
    System.out.println("the wrong number of elements were found");
    }

// check value of every pagename class element equals expected value
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
    String elementsValue = elements.get(i).getAttribute("value");
    if (elementsValue.equals(expected[i])) {
        System.out.println("passed on: " + elements);
    } else {
        System.out.println("failed on: " + elements);
    }
}
```

This has the obvious limitation of potentially having to store 200 odd text strings in the array and will therefore become unwieldy.  Is there a more elegant solution?  I could read the array values in from a .csv I guess and used Parameterized runner but then I'd still need to declare each value in the constructor right?

Comment: as far as your question `is there a more elegant solution`.. i think the way you are doing it is elegant.  You are looping through each one, i think this is perfectly fine.  Not sure if there is really a "better" solution.

Comment: thank you. Appreciate your comments

Comment: Fair warning - `WebDriver.findElements()` does not specify the order of the elements.  Your loop may or may not work, and the results may vary depending on which browser driver you're using.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Lists `contains` or `containsAll` function to determine equality. So basically like this:

```
final List<String> expectedElements = readFromCSV("expectedElements.csv");
final List<WebElement> elements = select.find.Elements(By.xpath( ".//*[starts-with(@id,'135')]"));

final List<String> stringElements = new ArrayList<>(elements.length);
for (WebElement element : elements) {
  stringElements.add(element.getAttribute("value"));
}

final boolean isSame = stringElements.containsAll(expectedElements);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a direct answer to your question, but only a few corrections to your code:**

1.

You can replace the code that you consider "ugly":

```
List<WebElement> elements = select.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id,'135')]"));
```

With a code that finds the elements using their `class` attribute:

```
List<WebElement> elements = select.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='pagename']"));
```

2.

Since non of these elements has a `value` attribute, you should replace the following line:

```
String elementsValue = elements.get(i).getAttribute("value");
```

With:

```
String elementsValue = elements.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Thank you barak - I appreciate your contribution.